# How to send terminate signal to the child process on exception, when using subprocess

Tags: python, linux, signals

I am running a python progam from another python program through subprocess, I am calling it like this.

```
try:
    subproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
shell=True)
    o, e = subproc.communicate()
    sys.stdout.write(o)
    sys.stderr.write(e)
except:
    subproc.terminate()
```

In the called program I have registered signal handlers like shown below. However, this never gets called on exception in the above program, despite calling the terminate function. But If I run the child program separately, the `handle_exit` function gets called fine. What mistake am I doing here?

```
def handle_exit(sig, frame):
    print('\nClean up code here)
    ....

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_exit)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_exit)
```

**UPDATE:**
OK, I got it working by replacing `subproc.terminate` with the following.

```
subproc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
subproc.wait()
```

That is good, but I would also want to get the output of the child process on exception. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution and here it is.

```
try:
    subproc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
shell=True)
    o, e = subproc.communicate()
except:
    subproc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    o, e = subproc.communicate()
sys.stdout.write(o)
sys.stderr.write(e)
```